# Why Javascript won't change color of the link?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to change color of a link on the fly like this:

```
 <Link
   to="/seo"
   name="seo"
   id="seo_link"
   alt="link to SEO section"
  >
  SEO
 </Link>
```

color is set in the stylesheet:

```
nav a {
    color: #00e6e6 !important;
    margin: 10px 15px 0 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

then I'm trying to change it depending on certain conditions:

```
 console.log("CALLED");
 document.getElementById("seo_link").style = "color: red !important";  // called but not changed
```

I can tell the change is being called thanks to the `console.log()` call but the text won't turn red.

Any advice ?

Comment: `document.getElementById("seo_link").style.color = "red"`

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: If on conditions you want to change the color in React, why directly manipulate the DOM anyway ? You can use your state and `className` to do it for you ? What @Sirko stated should also work and if not then, make the value as "red !important".

Comment: How are you making sure your code runs after the component is mounted? i.e rendered in DOM?

Comment: I know I can use state to change it it's just seemed such an overkill for this. I'll be changing links in a navbar so I'll have bunch of new states just for handling the change.

Comment: Is the `!important` in your CSS actually necessary? In general, this leads to situation like this, as it "disrupts" the rules for applying styles.

Comment: I wanna thank @LakshyaThakur  for nudging me into handling this with a state. It works nicely now. I'll delete this question in few days.